# Python Selenium Webdriver Message: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to write a Python script using selenium's webdriver, to automate the task of uploading invoices to the federal online ledger.

I know this is a common question, but after reading many questions in SO and trying their answers, I couldn't find a solution.

This is the html code I want to select and click on:

```
<input id="idcontribuyente" type="hidden" name="idContribuyente">
<input class="btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="button" style= "width:100%" onclick="document.getElementById('idcontribuyente').value='0';document.seleccionaEmpresaForm.submit();" role="button">
```

These are the main things I've tried so far:

(first with the WebDriverWait() and then with time.sleep(20), just in case there was an error there)

```
#1
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn_empresa")))
empresa_btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_empresa')
empresa_btn.click()

#2
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all')))
empresa_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all')
empresa_btn.click()

#3
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//input[@type='button']")))
empresa_btn =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//input[@type='button']")
empresa_btn.click()

#4
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='button']")))
empresa_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button']")
empresa_btn.click()

#5
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//td[@align="center"]/input')))
empresa_btn =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('//td[@align="center"]/input')
empresa_btn.click()

#6
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all']")))
empresa_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all']")
empresa_btn.click()
```

The error when using time.sleep(20):

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: element_name
```

The error when using WebDriverWait():

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Here's the full html code:
[image]

I'm pretty new to this. What am I doing wrong?

many thanks in advance!

**UPDATE - SOLUTION:**

I found a way, I've used a Selenium IDE and exported the code to inspect it. Apparently it had to do with switching windows. This code works (although it may be more verbose than it needs to be):

```
vars = {}
vars["window_handles"] = driver.window_handles

# This line already worked before. It is for the previous page
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='rcel']").click()

# Here it comes the way to select and click on the problematic button
def wait_for_window(timeout = 2):
    time.sleep(round(timeout / 1000))
    wh_now = driver.window_handles
    wh_then = vars["window_handles"]
    if len(wh_now) > len(wh_then):
        return set(wh_now).difference(set(wh_then)).pop()

vars["win806"] = wait_for_window(2000)
driver.switch_to.window(vars["win806"])
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn_empresa").click()
```

This is how the actual webpage looked like:
red triangle indicates the button I wanted to click on
[image]

Comment: Your 2nd xpath was correct and It might be in an iframe or shadow root.

Comment: Yes, it was correct, she just needed to add a wait before it, at least

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try...

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='idcontribuyente']/following-sibling::input")
```

Since it is 2 `input` tags next to each other, this finds the one by `ID` first and takes the `input` sibling directly after it.  Not sure it will work since I can't access the URL, but give it a shot

Comment: hey, thanks. It doesn't work either, same error :/

Comment: could you share the URL in your original post?  that may help us diagnose this better. Or at the very least, change that HTML screenshot to show more of the HTML.  Its possible there is an iFrame up there that you need to switch to, cant tell though from that current screenshot

Comment: I can't share the original URL cause you'd need to enter with an username and a password, but I changed the screenshot: now it's the full code. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

First wait, then click:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all')))
empresa_btn = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all').click()
```

Some of the steps you've tried were very close.

If the element you want to click is hidden, try using `driver.execute_script`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#idcontribuyente")
driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", element)
```

**Update 1**, try to click the second input:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all")
driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", element)
```

**Update 2**, probably you have few similar css locators similar to above:
try using:

```
tr:nth-of-type(4)>td>.btn_empresa.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all
```

**Update 3**
Check if your button is located inside shadow DOM. If it is - none of the methods you tried will work. Check how to enable showing shadow DOM.

**Update 4**
As mentioned in the comment to your question, your second xpath was good.
Try using it this way:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all']")))
empresa_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='btn_empresa ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all']").click()
```

Comment: I didn't even think of the wait, such an obvious thing :)  Good catch

Comment: They don't work... I added them to my attempts

Comment: Show on screenshot which element you want to click.

Comment: @vitaliis Thanks for the answers! It had to do with switching windows... I updated the question. I don't know if you refered to how the actual webpage looks like. I added a screenshot of that

Comment: Ok, good luck. The problem, according to your answer, was different from what you asked initially. Be more specific next time. Happy that your issue is solved.